# Using Sidekiq to run more complex jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

edit: It was actually really simple, I forgot to pass in `site` and `token`

I have setup Sidekiq and Redis on Heroku and I am able to get it to work with very simple jobs like this:

**order_worker.rb**

```
class OrderWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(num_orders)
      x=3*5
    end
end
```

But more complex jobs keep failing according to the Sidekiq web ui. Do I need to include ShopifyAPI and Faker somehow? I'm not super clear on what is being run. Is the entire app, with gems and all being created in a worker dyno?

**order_worker.rb**

```
class OrderWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(num_orders)
        include ShopifyAPI
        include Faker

        # Initialize session
        session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(site, token)
        ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)  

        #Create orders
        num_orders.times do
            new_order = ShopifyAPI::Order.new(
              :line_items => [
                ShopifyAPI::LineItem.new(
                  :quantity => 1,
                  :variant_id => 25701798472
                )
              ]
            )
            new_order.billing_address = ShopifyAPI::BillingAddress.new(:name => Faker::Name.name, :zip => zips[rnd], :country => 'United States', :province => states[rnd], :address1 => Faker::Address.street_address, :city => Faker::Address.city)
            new_order.email = r.rand(36**2).to_s(36) + '@yahoo.com'
            new_order.created_at = Faker::Time.backward(390, :evening)
            new_order.total_price = Faker::Number.decimal(3, 2)
            new_order.save
            @errs = @errs + new_order.errors.full_messages
            sleep 0.03
        end

    end


end
```

Comment: Probably is the `include` lines in the perform method, I suggest you to encapsulate all your login into a class, and then run your class in the perform method

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `OrderWorker#perform` is an *instance method*, which means it runs in the scope of instances of `OrderWorker`, not in the class `OrderWorker` itself. The instances don't have the method `include`. It belongs to the class. The consequence is that you'll get `NoMethodError`s when the task is run.

P.S. It seems that you don't have to `include` anything. Remove those `include`s inside `perform` will make your worker work.